# Calling dispatch_sync from a concurrent queue - does it block entirely?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, swift, grand-central-dispatch

Let's say I hypothetically call a dispatch_sync from a concurrent queue - does it block the entire queue or just that thread of execution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

dispatch_sync will block the caller thread until execution completes, a concurrent queue has multiple threads so it will only block one of those on that queue, the other threads will still execute.

Here is what Apple says about this:

> Submits a block to a dispatch queue for synchronous execution. Unlike
>   dispatch_async, this function does not return until the block has
>   finished. Calling this function and targeting the current queue
>   results in deadlock.
>
> Unlike with dispatch_async, no retain is performed on the target
>   queue. Because calls to this function are synchronous, it "borrows"
>   the reference of the caller. Moreover, no Block_copy is performed on
>   the block.
>
> As an optimization, this function invokes the block on the current
>   thread when possible.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_sync)

Comment: ... with the implied answer: no, it doesn't block an entire concurrent queue, because a concurrent queue consists of multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks for catching that Tommy, I misread the question. I have updated my answer.